# What minimum permissions should I set to give S3 file upload access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I used HTML and Javascript to upload a file on S3. I am facing a problem --> I created a role for unauthenticated entities and assigned the following policy to it.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:putObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I get an access denied error.But when I give the permission as

"s3:*"
I am able to upload the file. What minimum permissions can I give to make this work

Comment: I have tried with IAM role that has only `s3:PutObject`, `aws s3 cp` command can be used successfully.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi. Are you missing bucket arn? s3:ListBucket applies only to bucket, not its objects. Same for GetBucketLocation.

Comment: This works for me. Files are getting uploaded on the bucket. Thanks.

Comment: The /* ending of the bucket arn is very important. If you miss it you don't upload files to the bucket.

Comment: Today I hit an error `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied`. It turns out that `Resource` must contain both the bucket and bucket with wildcard for it to work.

Comment: Ivan Sainz, Thank you!  That was the critical point, I hadn't noticed before.

Answer (score 2):

For **Delete and Upload**, we can use permission

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```